# Git Pull - wiped out local changes

Tags: windows, git

I am using Git on Windows.

After numerous local changes and committing them locally I performed a Git pull from our remote repository. I found that after doing this and having a few conflicts, large amounts of code that existed locally are now gone without any backup files created on disk (ie .LOCAL).

**Is there a way to revert my state back to my local state before I did a remote pull?**

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of *gif wtf* ?

Comment: A little bit more detail would help quite a bit here.

Comment: You shouldn't expect backup *files*; the old content (assuming it was committed) is in the repository. That's what it's for.

Comment: It's actually quite unclear what you're trying to do here. Assuming those "large amounts of code" were committed... Do you want to reset to the commit before the merge? Restore the contents of only certain files from and recommit them? or restore them and ignore them?

Comment: @Jefromi - I was trying to reset to the commit before the merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For retrieving the entire branch:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

or for individual files:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: More likely some previous commit is what the OP wants, perhaps `HEAD^`.

Comment: @leaf Updated answer. I encourage you to take a look at: http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

Comment: Thanks, with your reference and answer I was able to get it restored.